# Calling a file from a website in Ruby

Tags: ruby, file, web, external

I'm trying to call resources (images, for example.) from my website to avoid constant updates. Thus far, I've tried just using this:

```
 @sprite.bitmap = Bitmap.new("http://www.minscandboo.com/minscgame/001-Title01.jpg")
```

But, this just gives "File not found error". What is the correct method for achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [**Net::HTTP**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/index.html) to get a local file first:

```
require 'net/http'

Net::HTTP.start("minscandboo.com") { |http|
  resp = http.get("/miscgame/001-Title01.jpg")
  open("local-game-image.jpg", "wb") { |file|
    file.write(resp.body)
   }
}

# ...

@sprite.bitmap = Bitmap.new("local-game-image.jpg")
```